# How to detect numbers/digits via builtin OcrEngine class

Tags: windows, multithreading, win-universal-app, ocr, c++-cx

I have troubles detecting digits/numbers in an image with the Windows UWP OCR-Engine from C++/CX.
I need to detect the number in the following Image

[image: Digit]

I tried it by using the builtin method for Windows 10 UWP: [OcrEngine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.ocr.ocrengine) with the following code:

```
...
cv::Mat croppedImage = imread("digit.png");
WriteableBitmap^ bit1 = ref new WriteableBitmap(croppedImage.cols, croppedImage.rows);
SoftwareBitmap^ bit2 = bit2->CreateCopyFromBuffer(bit1->PixelBuffer, BitmapPixelFormat::Bgra8, bit1->PixelWidth, bit1->PixelHeight);
Windows::Globalization::Language^ l = ref new Windows::Globalization::Language("de");
OcrEngine^ ocrEngine = OcrEngine::TryCreateFromLanguage(l);
IAsyncOperation<OcrResult^>^ ao = ocrEngine->RecognizeAsync(bit2);
task_completion_event<Platform::String^> purchaseCompleted;
auto deviceEnumTask = create_task(ao);
deviceEnumTask.then([this](OcrResult^ result)
{
App1::MainPage::findNumber(result->Text);
});
...
void App1::MainPage::findNumber(Platform::String^ text)
{
//Do something with String
}
```

My Problem is now, that the inserted string in `findNumber` is always null. I tried with different pictures as input but always the same result: NULL.

1. Is there an easier way to get the digits in this images in C++/CX?
2. What could be the problem? Converting the image?

Comment: There is an official [OCR sample in GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/OCR), you can have a check. However when I use it to recognize you image, it also can't recognize it. The  OcrEngine makes no guarantee that it can recognize the image properly. The accuracy of text recognition depends on the quality of the image. For more info, please see [Windows.Media.Ocr namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.ocr.aspx).

Comment: Thx for your answer.
In the meantime I found my mistake. The problem was the conversion of the SoftwareBitmap to a WriteableBitmap. I will post the solution later.
I also was not able to identify the single digit with OCR in my image. I changed the text from "2" to "Raum 2" and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the conversion of the WriteableBitmap to a SoftwareBitmap    WriteableBitmap^ bit1 = ref new WriteableBitmap(croppedImage.cols, croppedImage.rows);
            // Get access to the pixels
            IBuffer^ buffer = bit1->PixelBuffer;
            unsigned char* dstPixels;

```
        // Obtain IBufferByteAccess
        ComPtr<IBufferByteAccess> pBufferByteAccess;
        ComPtr<IInspectable> pBuffer((IInspectable*)buffer);
        pBuffer.As(&pBufferByteAccess);

        // Get pointer to pixel bytes
        pBufferByteAccess->Buffer(&dstPixels);
        memcpy(dstPixels, croppedImage.data, croppedImage.step.buf[1] * croppedImage.cols*croppedImage.rows);
        SoftwareBitmap^ bit2= ref new SoftwareBitmap(BitmapPixelFormat::Bgra8, croppedImage.cols, croppedImage.rows);
        //SoftwareBitmap^ bit2 = 
        bit2->CopyFromBuffer(bit1->PixelBuffer);
```